# How to create a role using ASP.NET pre-generated database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I am using ASP.NET MVC 5. I am creating a registration page to register an "expert", which I want to be a separate role from a user. I see that in the pre-generated AspNetRoles table there is an ID, and a Name column. Every time I try and research this I get something that shows how to create a page for an admin on how to literally create roles. I just want to get that role in my database, and then be able to assign it to a user when they are created using the experts registration page. I don't want a page that can make roles, I want to be able to do this directly in visual studio. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
private ApplicationUserManager _userManager;
public ApplicationUserManager UserManager
{
    get
    {
        return _userManager ?? 
        HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
    }
    private set
    {
        _userManager = value;
    }
}
```

Register User like this.

```
var user = new ApplicationUser {
    UserName = "John Doe",
    Email = "john.doe@foo.com"
};

// params: username and password
var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, "name_birthday_cheeky");
if (result.Succeeded)
{
    UserManager.AddToRole(user.Id, "expert");

    //code omitted for brevity
}
```

Comment: That answers one part of my question very well. Now I receive an error, "Role expert does not exist", which I expected. How do I get that role into the AspNetRole table? Other than just going in and typing it in. Because then other people working on this project will not have the same thing in their database. Is it something in the startup.cs?